# I'm getting this kind of error "list index out of range" python, how do I resolve it?

Tags: python

```
def Suffix_Border_Array(S):
    n = len(S)
    bs = [n-1]
    for i in range(1, n):
        bsLeft = bs[i+1]
        while bsLeft and S[i] != S[n-bsLeft-1]:
            bsLeft = bs[n-bsLeft]
        if S[i] == S[n-bsLeft-1]:
           bs.append(bsLeft+1)
        else:
            bs.append(0)
    return bs
```

The error is occurring on this line  `bsLeft = bs[i+1]`
How do I resolve this kind of error

Comment: Your `bs` only has one element, which is `n-1`.

Comment: it's trying to access an item/index beyond it's range..

Comment: It depend on what you want to use `bs` for. It is defined as a list of one item here: `bs = [n-1]` Did you mean: `bs = [0] * (n-1)`?

Comment: bs is a list with 1 element in it. You therefore can't reference a higher element in it. What are you trying to achieve with this script?

Comment: The original code is in C language, so I'm trying to write it in python `Suffix-Border-Array (S, bs)
{
n = strlen(S); bs[n - 1] = 0;
for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; --i)
{
bsLeft = bs[i + 1]; // Позиция с конца слева от предыдущей грани
while (bsLeft && (S[i] != S[n - bsLeft - 1]) ) bsLeft = bs[n - bsLeft];
// Длина на 1 больше, чем позиция
if (S[i] == S[n - bsLeft - 1]) bs[i] = bsLeft + 1;
else bs[i] = 0;
}
}`

Comment: @HaydenEastwood I'm  trying to print out the suffix array of a string say ABAABABAABAAB and the output array should be [10, 7, 2, 11, 8, 5, 0, 3, 12, 9, 6, 1, 4]

Comment: suffix_array = sorted(range(len(s)), key=lambda i: s[i:])

Comment: s = 'yourstring' eg 'ABAABABAABAAB'

Comment: @HaydenEastwood it worked thank you